# Python - Remove List-in-List Hierarchy?

Tags: python

What is **the most Pythonic way** of removing the list-in-list hierarchy?

That is, from

```
A=[[(1, 1), (2, 2)],[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)], [(1, 1)]]
```

to

```
B=[(1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"most pythonic" can be debated endlessly.  I prefer a nested list comprehension to flatten nested lists.

```
B = [element for sublist in A for element in sublist]
```

When it comes down to it, use what is most readable to *you* since you're likely the person who has to interface with your code most often.

Answer (score 2):

```
import operator
reduce(operator.add, A)
```

or

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, A)
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! But would you mind explaining a bit? What is the rationale behind this

Comment: You can take a look at [reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce). And in this case, `operator.add` means lambda x,y:x+y

Comment: **Note**, reduce has been deprecated and removed in Python 3.x. You would then need to use [functools.reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Answer (score 2):

Its more Pythonic to use [chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to unwrap a nested list

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(A))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

a = [[(1, 1), (2, 2)],[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)], [(1, 1)]]

list(itertools.chain(*a))
```

Check out the [itertools module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). Lot's of good stuff.